# How to select numerical sublists?

Tags: filtering

I got stuck with a simple problem:

Given a list of lists

```
ll={{1,2,3},{2,a},{Pi,4,5}}
```

I would like to select only those sublists which are numeric `-> {{1,2,3}, {Pi,4,5}}`.

I tried

```
Select[ll, (Map[Apply[And, NumericQ], #] &)]
```

which doesn't work.

How to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: `Cases[{__?NumericQ}] @ ll`

Comment: @Kuba Thanks for this nice solution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
Select[ll, AllTrue[#, NumericQ] &]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {[Pi], 4, 5}}

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't know `AllTrue`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann neither did I xD I was somehow convinced that All was a mathematica function for doing something like that (while it's actually all() and is a python function eheh), but while looking for it I found AllTrue in the documentation :P

Comment: Also: Select[AllTrue@NumericQ]@ll